# How to remove duplicate occurrences in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have any array that looks like this:

```
[
    { "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to CLOSE" }, 
    { "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30" }, 
    { "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30" }, 
    { "tempValue": "Tuesday  CLOSE to 08:30" }, 
    { "tempValue": "Thursday  CLOSE to 08:30" }
]
```

I need to remove all the dupliactes from this array. In the above example, the duplicates are `Sunday`...

So I tried something like this:

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}


unique(hours);
```

The variable `hours` is my array.

But my code above doesn't work!

Could someone please advice on this issue?

**EDIT:**

The desired output is this:

```
[
    { "tempValue": "Tuesday  CLOSE to 08:30" }, 
    { "tempValue": "Thursday  CLOSE to 08:30" }
]
```

Comment: What's your desired output? The array minus the 3rd item (duplicate of the 2nd item), = 4 items total, is that it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, please view my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: @jhujhul OP is looking to *remove* all items which have duplicates (not just the duplicates), given a particular logic for the string - his case is pretty different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way also:

```
var list  = [{"tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to CLOSE"}, {"tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"}, {"tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"}, {"tempValue": "Tuesday  CLOSE to 08:30"}, {"tempValue": "Thursday  CLOSE to 08:30"}];    
    function removeDuplicate(json){
    var uniques=[];
    var stringify={};
    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
       var keys=Object.keys(json[i]);
       keys.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
       var str='';
        for(var j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
           str+= JSON.stringify(keys[j]);
           str+= JSON.stringify(json[i][keys[j]]);
        }
        if(!stringify.hasOwnProperty(str)){
            uniques.push(json[i]);
            stringify[str]=true;
        }
    }
    return uniques;
}

var list = removeDuplicate(list);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Hi james, Its working..actually result display in console,  now i display on browser please check on this : https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxh6q8b/3/

Answer (score 2):

I'd first count up the number of occurrences of each day, and create an array containing only the days that occur more than once. Then, you can `.filter` by whether the day in an array item is included in that array:

```js
const input = [{
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to CLOSE"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Tuesday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Thursday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}];

const dayCountObj = input.reduce((a, { tempValue }) => {
  const day = tempValue.match(/^\S+/)[0];
  a[day] = (a[day] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
const daysToRemove = Object.entries(dayCountObj)
  .filter(([, count]) => count > 1)
  .map(([day]) => day);
  
const output = input.filter(({ tempValue }) => {
  const day = tempValue.match(/^\S+/)[0];
  return !daysToRemove.includes(day);
});
console.log(output);
```

If you want to reduce the computational complexity to `O(N)` instead of `O(N^2)`, use a Set instead of an array for the `daysToRemove`:

```js
const input = [{
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to CLOSE"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Sunday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Tuesday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}, {
    "tempValue": "Thursday  CLOSE to 08:30"
}];

const dayCountObj = input.reduce((a, { tempValue }) => {
  const day = tempValue.match(/^\S+/)[0];
  a[day] = (a[day] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
const daysToRemove = new Set(
  Object.entries(dayCountObj)
    .filter(([, count]) => count > 1)
    .map(([day]) => day)
);
  
const output = input.filter(({ tempValue }) => {
  const day = tempValue.match(/^\S+/)[0];
  return !daysToRemove.has(day);
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just your code with only 2 more commands:

```
function unique(list) {

  var result = [];
  var resultJson = [];

  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.tempValue, result) == -1) {
     result.push(e.tempValue);
     resultJson.push(e);
    }
  });
  return resultJson;
}

 unique(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution could be implemented as follows:

const unique = (hours) => [... new Set(hours)];

unique(hours);

Comment: @JamesJuanjie, `...` is the spread operator in js.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax